# Cryptocurrency forecasting app

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, array, cryptocurrency

I wrote a cryptocurrency (or any other) market forecasting application in Python 3.5. The code is getting bigger and more complex so I would love if some experts would take a look at it and check and look out for especially the following things:

- Loop indexes, range values, array indexes being correctly set (I find problems with this constantly)
- Correct exchange of values between global and local variables
- Local variables used in a nested loop should be nulled out before the 2nd loop
- Possibly making the code more efficient/faster/cleaner
- Other potential bugs

### Description

The app is in Python 3.5+. It loads in a `.csv` format file which contains the market data of BTC/USD for example. A dummy file can be downloaded here for testing: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/K4LwupcS)

**Then you have 3 options:**

- Backtest, which backtests the current configuration on the data
- Forecast, which forecasts `forward_steps` ahead into the future
- Brute force, which calculates the optimal parameter for the `period`

I would like if the aesthetics of the code would not be changed too much, I know it's messy, I am not a professional, just a hobbyist. So unless the change directly improves the speed or efficiency of the code, I'd like it to be left as it is. Otherwise, all bugs and problems should be fixed.

```
#☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀ ▶ dependencies ◀ ☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀

import os.path
import math

#☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀ ▶ parameters ◀ ☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀

version  = "2.6"
ARRAY    = []
FORECAST = []
file_name= "btc_usd.csv"
period   = 840
forward_steps =1
best_period   = 0
min_error     = 999999999999.0

#☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀ ▶ functions ◀ ☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀

def process_file():
    with open("data/"+file_name,'r') as f:
        lines=f.readlines() 
    ARRAY.append(['dummytime', 'dummyprice'])
    FORECAST.append('dummyforecast')
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        ARRAY.append(lines[i].strip().split(','))
        FORECAST.append("dummy")
    return (len(ARRAY) -1)

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

def linear_forecast_diff(limit,f_period):
      f_diff=0.0
      for i in range(limit-f_period+1,limit+1): # make it [,]
           f_diff=f_diff +   (float(ARRAY[i][1])-float(ARRAY[i-1][1]))
      f_diff/=f_period 
      return (f_diff)

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

def verification(limit,f_period_corrector,f_error_ignore,f_period):
   f_diff=linear_forecast_diff(limit,f_period)
   last_real    =float(ARRAY[limit+1][1])
   last_forecast=float(ARRAY[limit  ][1])+(f_diff*forward_steps)
   # manual correction for negative log values or zero division
   if(last_forecast<=0):
        f_period_corrector+=1
        f_error_ignore=True
        FORECAST[limit+1]="error"
       # print("here "+str(f_period)+" "+str(f_diff)+" "+str(limit))
        return (0,f_period_corrector,f_error_ignore)
   else:
        FORECAST[limit+1]=last_forecast
        error=abs(math.log(float(last_real/last_forecast)))   
        return (error,f_period_corrector,f_error_ignore)

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# formula: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17236_01/epm.1112/cb_statistical/frameset.htm?ch07s02s03s04.html
def theil_u():
   upper=0.0
   lower=0.0
   for x in range(1+period,arraysize-forward_steps): # N-1 for Theil's U
       if(ARRAY[x+1][1]!="error" and ARRAY[x+2][1]!="error" and FORECAST[x+1]!="error" and FORECAST[x+2]!="error"):
          cur_real       =float(ARRAY   [x+1][1])
          cur_forecast   =float(FORECAST[x+1])
          future_real    =float(ARRAY   [x+2][1])
          future_forecast=float(FORECAST[x+2])
          upper+= ((future_forecast-future_real)/cur_real)**2
          lower+= ((future_real-cur_real)       /cur_real)**2 
   if(upper!=0.0 and lower!=0.0):          
       theil=math.sqrt(upper/lower)
       return (theil)

   else:
       return (1)       

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

def user_interaction():
   print ("\n")
   print ("Choose Option!")
   print ("Backtest: 0")
   print ("Forecast: 1")
   print ("Brute Force: 2")
   return(input())

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

def main_function(f_period,f_best_period,f_min_error):
   if(userinput=="0" or userinput=="2" ):
        error=0.0
        period_corrector=0
        error_ignore=False
        theilu=0.0
        for k in range(1+f_period,arraysize-forward_steps+1): # +1 to fill the [] zone , -1 to go until the prev value
            output=verification(k,period_corrector,error_ignore,f_period)
            if(output[2]==False):
              error+=output[0] 
            error_ignore=False
        error/= (arraysize-f_period-forward_steps-output[1])

        if(userinput=="2" ):
          if (error<f_min_error):
            f_min_error=error 
            f_best_period=f_period

        if(userinput=="0"):
            theilu=theil_u()
            print ("    "+'\033[103m'+'\033[1m'  +"Profitgenerator's CRYPTO FORECASTING TOOL v"+version+ '\033[0m')
            print ("\n")
            print ("    Mode:              "+"Backtest")
            print ("    File Name:         "+file_name)
            print ("    From:              "+str(ARRAY[1][0])+" to "+str(ARRAY[arraysize][0]))
            print ("    Array Size:        "+str(arraysize))
            print ("    Period:            "+str(f_period))
            print ("    Forward Steps:     "+str(forward_steps)) 
            print ("    Iterations:        "+str((arraysize-f_period-forward_steps)))
            print ("    "+'\033[106m' +'\033[1m'  +"LN Error:          "+str(error)+ '\033[0m'    )
            print ("    Theil's U:         "+str(theilu))
            if(theilu<1):
                print ("    "+'\033[102m'+'\033[1m'  +"Predictive Edge:   "+str((1-theilu)) + '\033[0m')
            else:
                print ("    "+'\033[101m'+'\033[1m'  +"Predictive Edge:   "+str((1-theilu)) + '\033[0m')

   if(userinput=="1"): 
        difference=linear_forecast_diff(arraysize,f_period)
        lastprice=float(ARRAY[arraysize][1])
        forecast=lastprice+(difference*forward_steps)
        print ("    "+'\033[103m'+'\033[1m'  +"Profitgenerator's CRYPTO FORECASTING TOOL v"+version+ '\033[0m')
        print ("\n")
        print("    Mode:                  "+"Forecast")
        print("    File Name:             "+file_name)
        print("    Array Size:            "+str(arraysize))
        print("    Period:                "+str(f_period))
        print("    Forward Steps:         "+str(forward_steps)) 
        print("    Last Price:            "+str(lastprice))
        print("    "+'\033[106m' +'\033[1m'  +"Forecasted Next Price: "+str(forecast)+ '\033[0m')
  # print(f_best_period,f_min_error)
   return (f_best_period,f_min_error)
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -


#☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀ ▶ main ◀ ☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀☀


arraysize=process_file()


if((period+forward_steps)>arraysize-2):
   period=1
   forward_steps=1
userinput     = user_interaction()


print ("\n\n")
if(userinput=="0" or userinput=="1" ):
   main_function(period,best_period,min_error)
if(userinput=="2" ):
   for period in range (1,arraysize-forward_steps):
     main_output=main_function(period,best_period,min_error) # +1 to fill the [] zone
     best_period=main_output[0]
     min_error  =main_output[1]
   print ("    Mode:                  "+"Brute Force")
   print ("    Forward Steps:         "+str(forward_steps)) 
   print ("    Best Period:           "+str(best_period)) 
   print ("    Error:                 "+str(min_error))  
print ("\n\n")
```

Comment: Just to note, the code you post here, and we do, is licensed implicitly as [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). This is stated in the footer of all pages. So you may not be able to take code from an answer and add it straight to your MIT code.

Comment: @Peilonrayz well I have posted the code in other places too under MIT license, so from my point of view I don't care which license people use. As for contributor's code,okay fair enough, still good as an inspiration source, I would just like if somebody would take a look at it and debug it.